# Retrieve computed property from server

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Considering the following model:

```
public class ProfileViewModel
{
    public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
    public ProfileLocalizationViewModel CurrentLocalization { get; set; }
    public List<ProfileLocalizationViewModel> Localizations { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to achieve is have the `CurrentLocalization` be retrieved automatically from the `Localizations` based on the `LanguageCode`. I know about the `ko.computed()` function, but I am going to pass a list of `ProfileViewModel` to the client, so setting the `CurrentLocalization` as a computed property manually in knockout I don't think is an option. Is it possible to achieve what I want? If no, how could I achieve something similar? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cant you do that in C#, instead of having default `get;`, have your own implementation of `get{ }`.

Comment: I tried to do that afterwards but it doesn't get mapped as a computed property in knockout...

Answer (score 0):

If you want it on server side that you may want something like:

```
public class ProfileViewModel
{
    public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
    public ProfileLocalizationViewModel CurrentLocalization 
    { 
       get{
         return Localizations.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.LanguageCode == this.LanguageCode); //assuming that ProfileLocalizationViewModel has LanguageCode property
       } 
    }
    public List<ProfileLocalizationViewModel> Localizations { get; set; }
}
```

It has nothing to do with knockout computed property. It is a server side code.

Comment: Sorry, I maybe wasn't explicit enough. What I want is the  `CurrentLocalization` be retrieved automatically from the `Localizations` based on the `LanguageCode` on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have a viewmodel with `Localizations` and `LanguageCode`, you can create a computed observable like this:

```
var currentLocalization = ko.computed(function() {
    var code = LanguageCode(); // unwrap observable
    var currentLocalizacion 
      = localizations.find(function(loc) {return loc.langCode === code});;
    return currentLocalization
};
```

In this implementation I'm using [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), which isn't available in all browsers. If you need to support browsers that doesn't have this method, you can use a library like [lodash](https://lodash.com/) ([_.find](https://lodash.com/docs#find)), or any alternative implementation, like a `for` loop to search inside the array elements.